# Can i still use PHP GET variable with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a page that takes a `GET` variable, q from the URL using the following code:

```
<?php ob_start(); session_start();
$q=trim($_GET['q']);  // this is for security purposes
if (!is_numeric($q)){
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
}
?>
```

The current URL looks like `localhost/s/index.php?q=345`.  I will soon write a .htaccess file that makes the URL look like localhost/345.  I was wondering if i could still grab the `GET` variable (q) using the code above.  I'm concerened it wont work because the URL won't have the typical `GET` appearance.  In the new URL the "GET" variable will look like a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `RewriteRule` substitution string doesn't contain a `?` intro then the query string is left unchanged.  If it does and you also specify a `[qsa]` flag then the existing query string will be appended to the new one in your substitution string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you use mod-rewrite, it is 'rewritten' into a different format. Your htaccess will then specify how to interpret the new format, so your values will be there, its up to you on the formatting of your htaccess to make them get variables.

Comment: "GET variables" (in PHP terminology) are values specified in the query portion of a URL, after the question mark.  `.htaccess` doesn't define what constitutes a GET variable.